# select card rectangle from captured image iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am working in iOS application where I want to select card rectangle from captured image using camera. So if anybody knows any solution please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: your `select card rectangle from captured image` means cut out of a image?

Comment: Yes I want to cut the image and the resulting image should be card rectangle area.

Answer (score -1):

My code is below:

```
/**
 *  Cut out a image to a new image with the rect
 *
 *  @param image UIImage image origin image
 *  @param rect  CGRect rect the rect area you want
 *
 *  @return UIImage
 */
+ (UIImage *)ct_imageFromImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect{

    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGFloat x= rect.origin.x*scale,y=rect.origin.y *scale,w=rect.size.width*scale,h=rect.size.height*scale;
    CGRect dianRect = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    //cut the image with the rect area
    CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImageRef, dianRect);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ aircraft for your reply. I just have one query that what will be the rect parameter value here

Comment: @PradumnaPatil, my method should put in `Util` file, and after your capture the photo, invoke the method, put in the photo image and the rect you want, you can get the result you want.

Comment: Yes I have put your method in Util class but should I am not able to understand what should I put in the rect params can you please explain. Thank you

Comment: @PradumnaPatil， means `I want to select card rectangle from captured image` of the `card rectangle`.

Comment: But how I can select the card rectangle exactly.

Comment: @PradumnaPatil, you just set it, the position and the size, you can base on the image's size.